# Hosting REST api in web server or application server

Tags: rest, web-services, webserver, application-server

I would like to know if there is any difference in hosting REST web service APIs in a web server or application server, is there any reason one is preferred over the other?

Answer (score 2):

So i think you are confused about what are application servers and web servers.

**Application Server** is the name of a *machine/server* which is running any application used by an organization and it depends of any other servers to run the application functionalities correctly, like **Database Servers, Caching Servers and other kind of servers**.

**Web server** is a software which puts an application online for being accessed by clients through the web.

**An application server commonly has a web server running inside it**, as part of a stack needed to run the application in the server, like libraries and other sofwares need to execute the application objective.

So you can run a REST api inside of an application server with help of the web server application.

Some examples of web servers are **Apache, Nginx, LightHttpd, etc.**